# Arduino + Ethernet Shield hangs after some time

Tags: arduino, ethernet

I am using an arduino to retrieve some data from a web application. The problem is that after some time it starts to hang.

For testing I used the default `EthernetClient` sketch and modified it a bit that every few secounds there is send a request to the server to get the information. For testing I don't do anything with the data I get so it does only send the request and retrieve the data.

For testing I use a Arduino Mega 2560  + Ethernet Shield and a Arduino Ethernet board, I experience the problem on both. It runs from 30 minutes up to one day then the whole board freezes. The boards doesn't get hot or anything else.

At first it seams to work but after some undefined time it starts to hang, does anyone have an idea what could cause this? Is there a bug on the arduino or the W5100 Ethernet chip?

Would you try to fix this issue or switch to a Raspberry Pi? Using the watchdog timer is no option because it doen't work on the Mega without changing the bootloader.

**UPDATE** (Added my loop code, there are no memory issues, I testet that before):

```
void loop()
{
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();

    delay(2000);

    if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
      Serial.println("connected");
      client.println("GET / HTTP/1.0");
      client.println();
    }
  }
}
```

This is all it does, in the setup there is the default initialization code from the Ethernet demo sketch.

**UPDATE 2**

Testing with Arduino Mega + WiFi Shield hangs too.

Testing with EtherMega 2560 from freetronics is now running 2 days without any problems I will continue this for min. one week. My only problem with this bord is the price. It's around 100$.

Comment: Have you run out of memory? Used up some other resource?

Comment: You really need to post a bit of code for a question like this. It might be something as simple as you are not handling disconnections / timeouts from the server correctly which might account for why it appears somewhat random.

Comment: Updated my post. (Testing this actually on a EtherMega 2560 from freetronics and a Mega 2560 with WiFi Shield) they are running now since 30 minutes, I let you now if both or one of them hangs.

Comment: So what is the output of the Serial Monitor when it "hangs"

Comment: It permanently prints the content of a website, when it hangs it is somewhere in the HTML file. (Added my testing results with with the too other Arduinos as Update)

Comment: Can client.read() hang? You don't check for errors during/after that call. Can you add a line before client.read(), something like `serial.print("read ");`? The later call to print() would then add the character just read.

Comment: Ok, some news, the other tested Boards / Shields hang too, now testing the Arduino Due with Ethernet Shield if this fails to I will talk to the Arduino developers if this is a bug in the Boards or the Shield. I keep you updated.

Comment: I have the same problem with the Uno and WiFi Shield. Any news on this?

Comment: Any news on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

[Here](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/WebClient) is a working solution testet with Mega (1.0.1) and Due (1.5.3)

<del>Ok, it seams there is a bug in the **arduino 1.0.x** libraries that causes the ethernet module to hang after some time, when you have to permanetly query a server.</del>

<del>With the **Arduino Due (arduino 1.5.2)** it is now running and also much faster! So its maby the best option to use this when you have to deal with much network traffic and many operations. I will contact the arduino developers about this issue and update this answer when I got more information about this problems.</del>